# Add select input with pre defined classes to insert image screen?

Tags: images, select, input

I'm looking for a way to add a select element (or some multiselect variant) with pre-defined classes to the image insertion screen in Wordpress.

I've been looking around for some way to do this but am unable to find a solution, so does anyone here know if/how it can be done?

Having non-techy clients or colleagues remember class names and adding them to the input field is not really workable for me.

[image: Possible to add a select input with classnames here?]